# How to change timezone in localhost in wampserver?

Tags: php, timezone, localhost, laravel-5.4, wampserver

How to change timezone in `localhost` in `wampserver`. i will try to change in `php.ini` file in **`date.timezone ="Asia/Kolkata"`** but can't change time so..now what i'm to for changing time ??

> > php.ini

[image]

> phpinfo()

[image]

Her which file is right ...first in php.ini file is not avalibale and
2nd file in i will also change time.

Comment: Did you restart PHP? Any changes would take effect after this. FYI, please do not post your config as image.

Comment: Yes.!! i do but not change time ...

Comment: Is it possible, that you changed the "wrong" ini? "[CLI Server]" can be a hint, that you changed the php.ini for PHP-CLI, which is used for php on command line. Check which php.ini file is included for your web server, e.g. call a script with *phpinfo();* from browser.

Comment: I don't know how the wamp server works, but in an usual php installation, there are two seperate php.ini files (cli and fpm).

Comment: Sorry .!! i cant understabd because i can just one ini file how to find second ini file ?

Comment: Create a php script, that you can call from browser (e.g. http://localhost/info.php. That script has just following content: <?php phpinfo(); ?> That will print a table of included configs, modules etc. Look for ini-files section (should be at the beginning of content).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.!! its working if php.ini file in `date.timezone="time"` can change and restart your server.